# When to close a TcpClient connection

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I'm having trouble understanding the proper flow when a TcpListener and TcpClient communicate with each other.

I have a program that starts up a TcpListener on port 8088 and listens for TcpClient connections.

I have another program that creates a TcpClient (let's call it DataSender1) and connects to the TcpListener in the other program and sends it data.

If DataSender1 is a program that runs constantly (like a service) and pushes data to the TcpListener regularly over time, when should the TcpListener close DataSender1's connection? Should I close the connection after I receive and process each distinct message from DataSender1? Or, whenever I decide to shut down the TcpListener? Do I create a new connection each time DataSender1 is ready to send data?

I'm running into an issue in an actual application where the TcpListener aborts the connection whenever my TcpClient sends 202 messages. I have no idea why it constantly aborts on message 202.

Comment: As far as I know you need to keep communication otherwise the socket will timeout, you can't just have one-way traffic, you need to ack your messages.

Comment: @ikwillem Sockets don't timeout by default, unless you are setting timeouts in your own code. And there is nothing wrong with 1-way communications, and you certainly don't need to manually ACK messages received over TCP, as TCP itself handles that at the transport layer for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: _"Sockets don't timeout by default"_ -- unfortunately, they kind of do. That is, you are correct that the _socket_ itself won't. But most people are using network connections behind a NAT router or other proxy, and these will typically discard connection state for a mapped connection if it's idle for too long, effectively disconnecting the socket.

Comment: As I was googling myself I saw why I thought the need for a two way connection is there. If you do a read off the stream, on the sending-end, that read action will not receive any data, which will result in a timeout. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.receivetimeout?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @PeterDuniho true, though it really depends on the particular NAT being used. For example, what you describe is common for FTP transfers passing through an FTP-unaware NAT. The command channel might get closed during a lengthy transfer on the data channel, unless the NAT knows FTP is being used so it won't close the command channel while a transfer is in progress, or if TCP keep-alives are enabled on the command channel.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but mainly too broad. The `TcpListener` object isn't involved in a connection _at all_, other than handling the initial inbound request for a connection. It cannot "abort" a connection. Only the `TcpClient` returned by it could. As far as that goes, it's not normal for a client socket to disconnect unexpectedly, and especially not for it to do so consistently at a specific number of operations. There is a bug in your system and without a [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, no good answer can be provided. ...

Comment: ... As far as when to intentionally close the connection, that depends entirely on what application protocol you're implementing. Some, like the early versions of HTTP, require a new connection for each request. Others, including later option for HTTP, allow multiple requests for a single connection. In general, it's desirable to keep the connection open as long as you'll need it, because it's slow to reestablish any given connection.

Comment: @ikwillem: _"If you do a read off the stream, on the sending-end, that read action will not receive any data, which will result in a timeout"_ -- not unless one has explicitly set a timeout for the socket. It's _very_ unusual to do so. Indeed, because reading from a stream and getting a response with a length of 0 bytes is _the_ indicator for graceful shutdown of a TCP connection, it is common for both endpoints to issue a read operation, even if data will only ever be sent one way.

Comment: @PeterDuniho "response of with a length of 0 bytes is the indicator for graceful shutdown of a TCP connection" that's it, exactly what i ment.

Comment: _"exactly what i ment"_ -- well, there's a vast difference between _"timeout"_ and _"response with a length of 0 bytes"_ -- they are two completely different things -- so I don't see how what you wrote could have been meant to be exactly the same as what I did. :(

Answer (score 1):

> If DataSender1 is a program that runs constantly (like a service) and pushes data to the TcpListener regularly over time, when should the TcpListener close DataSender1's connection?

Unless your communication protocol dictates that the TcpListener should close the connection, then it shouldn't close the connection at all, unless an I/O error occurs on the connection, the TcpClient has disconnected its end of the connection, or the TcpListener is being shutdown.  The TcpClient should decide when to close the connection, such as when it is not going to be sending/receiving any data for awhile.

If the connection is going to sit idle for awhile, but it should still be left open for whatever reason, then the TcpClient and TcpListener should implement some kind of ping/pong messaging between them.  Or, you could just enable TCP keep-alives at the transport layer.

> Should I close the connection after I receive and process each distinct message from DataSender1?

There is overhead in tearing down a connection and re-establishing a new connection.  So try to avoid that as much as possible.  If you are sending data frequently, there is no good reason to close the connection.

For example, HTTP is a stateless protocol.  So in HTTP 0.9, and in HTTP 1.0 by default, a connection is closed after a response is sent, and a new request would require a new connection.  But as the Internet evolved, and WWW pages grew in complexity, and so HTTP traffic usage increased, it was found to be more efficient to leave the HTTP connections open and reuse them whenever possible (especially if SSL/TLS is used).  Which is why using persistent connections is now the default behavior in HTTP 1.1.

Most other TCP-based Internet protocols depend on persistent connections to maintain user state.

If you are designing your own custom communication protocol between your TcpClient and TcpListener, then you get to decide how your connections are to be managed.

> Do I create a new connection each time DataSender1 is ready to send data?

Only if it is not already connected to the TcpListener.  Whether it disconnects afterwards depends on your design and architectural needs.

> I'm running into an issue in an actual application where the TcpListener aborts the connection whenever my TcpClient sends 202 messages. I have no idea why it constantly aborts on message 202.

Then you likely have a bug in your TcpListener code that you need to find and fix.  Which is what a debugger is meant for.  Put some breakpoints in the TcpListener's code, and step through the code to see what the TcpListener does when message 202 is received.